# Text Box Search / Javascript Function Arrays **not corresponding**

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want the user to "Search" some "Authors" and if they select the one in the database they are sent to a corresponding HTML. Otherwise "No Author Found" displays...

For some reason I cannot wrangle it properly - pls help!

```
//Search by Author
                    function searchAuth() {
              var search_string = document.getElementById('search_string').value;
              var arrayelement = ["John","Stan","Henry","Paul","Samuel"];
              for (i=0;i<arrayelement.length;i++) {
              if (input == arrayelement.John) {
                 var itemLink = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
              "<a href='https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl'>Your link</a>";
            } else if (input == arrayelement.Stan) {
                 var itemLink = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
              "<a href='https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl'>Your link</a>";
            }else {
      var itemLink = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
      "Author not found."
    }
}



<!--Author-->  
                <h3>Search By Author</h3>
            <form name="searchTest" onsubmit="return(searchAuth());" action="#">
            <input type="text" id="search_string" />
            <input type="submit"/>
            <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `arrayelement.John` won't work.. do a `[]` bracket notation  when you are getting objects in an array.

Comment: what is `input` ? where are you getting the **input**? is input = `search_string`?

Comment: @JF-Mechs sorry - if (search_string ==arrayelement[John]) ...like this?

Comment: see answer below .. let me know if it fixes your issues :)

Comment: @JF-Mechs Will do! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to do things like these..

P.S this is just a demo, for you to start :)

**EDIT**: added few explanation on some stuffs you might get confuse with. :)

```js
//events once textbox gets out focus
//the events varies on which or where do you want to add the event. it can be on click of a search button or submit button just like in your example.
document.getElementById('search-text-box-id').addEventListener("focusout", function() {
    //searchString gets the textbox value.
    var searchString = document.getElementById('search-text-box-id').value;
    var searchList = ["John","Stan","Henry","Paul","Samuel"];
    //Loop searchList
    for (i=0; i < searchList.length; i++) {
      //i which usually means the index or the key of the array's object(s).
      var searchItem = "";
      //searchList[i] loops its object by getting the index resulting to John, Stan and so on and so forth.
      if (searchString == searchList[i]) {
        searchItem = searchList[i];
        document.getElementById('search-result-container').innerHTML = searchItem + " link";
        //stop looping as the loop found a match.
        return;
      }
      else {
       searchItem = "Author not found.";
        document.getElementById('search-result-container').innerHTML = searchItem;
      } 
    }
});
```

```html
<label for="search-text-box"></label>
<input type="text" id="search-text-box-id" name="search-text-box" />
<p id="search-result-container"></p>
```